# Selenium RC doesn't run the test suite by BAT file

Tags: java, batch-file, selenium, selenium-rc

I've tried to run my test suite by Selenium RC through a BAT file.

Actually it worked OK until yesterday morning and it stopped to run my test suite.

Probably because I've added user-extensions.js and since that I can't run my test suite by the selenium RC.

How can I add this script to my test suite?

I'm using Selenium IDE for to write my test cases, so I guess that make this more complex problem..

This is the console log of the BAT file during the execution:
>

```
C:\automation>cd C:\automation\screenshots\
C:\automation\screenshots>del *.png
Could Not Find C:\automation\screenshots\*.png
10:46:38.926 INFO - Launching a standalone server
10:46:39.098 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.25-b02
10:46:39.098 INFO - OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
10:46:39.113 INFO - v2.44.0, with Core v2.44.0. Built from revision 76d78cf
10:46:39.238 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.
1:4444/wd/hub
10:46:39.238 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
10:46:39.238 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@6e3c1e
69
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server
/driver]
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
10:46:39.379 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@b1bc7ed
jar:file:/C:/automation/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar!/customProfileDirC
USTFFCHROME
10:46:39.535 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
10:46:42.666 INFO - Launching Firefox...
10:46:44.245 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

This is the code line from the BAT file:

```
java -jar C:\automation\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://www.mywebsite.com" "C:\automation\emailSanity.html" "C:\automation\testing_results.html" -port 4444
```

This is the screenshot of the actual result of the Selenium RC in action:
http://i57.tinypic.com/28u71jl.png

Please your help!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your app is at the splash screen, I can only assume that you forgot to put in your URL to initially open.

Since you are using RC, then your first statement of your test script should be:

```
selenium.open("http://example.com"); // where example.com is the app is your SUT.
```